# Cannot iterate with ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have component that gets data from back-end and group it

Here is code

```
 getRecruitmentAgencyClientPositions(): void {
    this._recruitmentAgencyClientsService.getRecruitmentAgencyClientPositions(this.recruitmentAgencyClientId).subscribe(r => {
        this.groupedArray = _.groupBy(r.items, 'groupIdentifier');
        console.log(this.groupedArray);
    });
}
```

Here is how I got it like this

```
 {
  "57a5bcdf-fdf0-494a-ba94-8c50ebb716cf": [
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "57a5bcdf-fdf0-494a-ba94-8c50ebb716cf",
      "salary": 100,
      "commission": 5,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-27T18:00:48+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 5
    }
  ],
  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000": [
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 100,
      "commission": 20,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:23:18+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 7
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 123,
      "commission": 1,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:23:42+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 8
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 100,
      "commission": 20,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:30:47+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 9
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 20,
      "commission": 20,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:31:36+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 10
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 20,
      "commission": 1,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:35:20+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 11
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 20,
      "commission": 3,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:35:26+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 12
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 666,
      "commission": 3,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:42:08+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 13
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 111,
      "commission": 23,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:42:49+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 14
    },
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 2,
      "commission": 2,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:42:52+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 15
    }
  ]
}
```

And I try to generate tables according to grouping like this

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of groupedArray">
<div class="primeng-datatable-container positions-table" [busyIf]="primengTableHelper.isLoading">
    <p-table
        #dataTablech
        [value]="item"
        rows="{{ primengTableHelper.defaultRecordsCountPerPage }}"
        [paginator]="false"
        dataKey="id"
        ScrollWidth="100%"
    >
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    {{ 'Id' | localize }}
                </th>
                <th>
                    {{ 'Salary' | localize }}
                </th>
                <th>
                    {{ 'Commission' | localize }}
                </th>              
            </tr>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-record="$implicit">
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.salary }} £</td>
                <td>{{ item.commission }} %</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
    <div class="primeng-no-data" *ngIf="!primengTableHelper.records">
        {{ 'NoData' | localize }}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But I get error like this

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

How I can fix this?

Comment: As your log shows, `groupedArray` is an object, not a list shown by the `{}` The lists you want to itereate seem to be inside of the object properties i.e: `57a5bcdf-fdf0-494a-ba94-8c50ebb716cf`

Comment: groupedArray is not an array. It's an object whose properties are arrays.

Comment: How I can iterate via arrays from objects? @Fussel

Comment: How I can iterate via arrays from objects? @jarmod

Comment: You probably had an array already (`r.items`) before you used lodash to group it.

Comment: I need to group it by field, and then get arrays from grouped object @jarmod

Comment: Then you probably should have two data structures: an array of unique groupidentifiers (sorted in whatever way makes sense to your users) plus the groupedBy structure that you already have above. And you'll need two ngFor loops: the outer loop iterates over the groupidentifier list (of unique groupidentifier values) and the inner loop iterates over `groupedArray[groupidentifier]` which is the array of objects for the given groupidentifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the error, `ngFor` is only used to iterate over arrays, not objects.
To turn an object into an array, you can use e.g. `Object.values()` or `Object.keys()`. In your case, the keys are the same as the property `groupIdentifier`, so I suggest you use the `Object.values()`.

The easiest example would add `Object.values` into `ngFor`:

```
*ngFor="let item of Object.values(groupedArray)"
```

Please notice, that the result will be interation over:

```
[
  [
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "57a5bcdf-fdf0-494a-ba94-8c50ebb716cf",
      "salary": 100,
      "commission": 5,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-27T18:00:48+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 5
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "groupIdentifier": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "salary": 100,
      "commission": 20,
      "recruitmentAgencyClientId": 10,
      "isDeleted": false,
      "deleterUserId": null,
      "lastModifierUserId": null,
      "creationTime": "2020-11-30T17:23:18+02:00",
      "creatorUserId": 3,
      "id": 7
    },
    ...
  ]

]
```

Which means, you will actually need second `ngFor`.

The best solution to this problem, would be map values properly when getting them from the backend. For example:

```
getRecruitmentAgencyClientPositions(): void { 
    this._recruitmentAgencyClientsService.getRecruitmentAgencyClientPositions(this.recruitmentAgencyClientId).subscribe(r => {
        const groupedObject = _.groupBy(r.items, 'groupIdentifier'); // object of arrays
        const groupedArrays = Object.values(groupedObject); // array of arrays
        this.groupedArray = groupedArrays.reduce((flatArray, current) => flatArray.concat(current), []); //flatting arrays, final result
        console.log(this.groupedArray);
    });
}
```

This way `*ngFor="let item of groupedArray"` should work like a charm.

**UPDATE**
To iterate per group you can just don't flat the arrays.

```
getRecruitmentAgencyClientPositions(): void { 
    this._recruitmentAgencyClientsService.getRecruitmentAgencyClientPositions(this.recruitmentAgencyClientId).subscribe(r => {
        const groupedObject = _.groupBy(r.items, 'groupIdentifier'); // object of arrays
        this.groupedArray = Object.values(groupedObject); // array of arrays
        console.log(this.groupedArray);
    });
}
```

This way, `groupedArray` is array, and each element in this array is one group.

Comment: But I need grouped data, because I need to generate table per group. So this solution not fits for me :(

Comment: I updated post. Please check out if updated answer is a solution for your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Data you are getting in groupedArray is not an array. its an object with 2 arrays inside it.

If I am not wrong
first array is : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
second array is : "57a5bcdf-fdf0-494a-ba94-8c50ebb716cf".

if you want to convert this to array, Push content of this both arrays to one array then you can iterate.

Like this :

```
function convertToArray(array){
    let gArray=[];
    array["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"].forEach(data=>{
        gArray.push(data);
      });

    array["57a5bcdf-fdf0-494a-ba94-8c50ebb716cf"].forEach(data=>{
         gArray.push(data)
      });
   return gArray;
}
```

Comment: But I don't need to merge them in one array, all point, that I need to group it